# How can I group RDD by key then count per unique string?

Tags: pyspark

I have an RDD like:

```
[(1, "Western"),
(1, "Western")
(1, "Drama")
(2, "Western")
(2, "Romance")
(2, "Romance")]
```

I wish to count per userID the occurances of each movie genres resulting in

```
1, { "Western", 2), ("Drama", 1) } ...
```

After that it's my intention to pick the one with the largest number and thus gaining the most popular genre per user.

I have tried `userGenre.sortByKey().countByValue()`
but to no avail I have no clue on how I can perform this task. I'm using pyspark jupyter notebook.

EDIT:

I have tried the following and it seems to have worked, could someone confirm?

```
userGenreRDD.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).aggregateByKey(\
                  0, # initial value for an accumulator \
                  lambda r, v: r + v, # function that adds a value to an accumulator \
                  lambda r1, r2: r1 + r2 # function that merges/combines two accumulators \
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('u1', "Western"),('u2', "Western"),('u1', "Drama"),('u1', "Western"),('u2', "Romance"),('u2', "Romance")])
```

The occurrence of each movie genre could be

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize(rdd.countByValue().items())
>>> rdd.map(lambda ((x,y),z): (x,(y,z))).groupByKey().map(lambda (x,y): (x, [y for y in y])).collect()
[('u1', [('Western', 2), ('Drama', 1)]), ('u2', [('Western', 1), ('Romance', 2)])]
```

Most popular genre

```
>>> rdd.map(lambda (x,y): ((x,y),1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).map(lambda ((x,y),z):(x,(y,z))).groupByKey().mapValues(lambda (x,y): (y)).collect()
[('u1', ('Western', 2)), ('u2', ('Romance', 2))]
```

Now one could ask what should be most popular genre if more than one genre have the same popularity count?